# how to pass parameter in facebook redirect_uri

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, httprequest, http-redirect

I'm using https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorizeclient_id=APP_ID&redirect_uri=MY_URL&scope=user_likes,friends_likes

to get permissions from user to access his information. after that i'm being redirected to MY_URL, the problem is that i need to pass a parameter to MY_URL.
i would like to do something like:
MY_SITE?parameter=test.

how do i do it without mixing with outer parameters?

thanks!

Comment: By properly URL-encoding the whole redirect_uri parameter value, of course.

Comment: can you explain more please?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=what+is+url+encoding%3F

Answer (score 0):

Use `urlencode(MY_URL)` instead of `MY_URL`

Comment: This does not answer the question.  The OP is not asking about url encoding, but rather how to tell Facebook to whitelist a redirect URI which includes parameters that are not static.

Answer (score 0):

Replace MY_URL with `encodeURIComponent(MY_URL)` using javascript. For example:

```
window.location = 'https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorizeclient_id=APP_ID&redirect_uri='+encodeURIComponent(MY_URL)+'&scope=user_likes,friends_likes';
```

Comment: This does not answer the question.  The OP is not asking about url encoding, but rather how to tell Facebook to whitelist a redirect URI which includes parameters that are not static.